# Open a PHP page with window.location in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, window.location, location-href

How do I open a php page from javascript function ?

1. `window.location = "http://www.google.com";`
2. `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";`
3. `location.href = "http://www.google.com";`

None of them is working.
Even put in php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

What is wrong at my approach?

Comment: can you please paste the full code ?

Comment: alert something and make sure code is in flow.

Comment: `window.location` is right approach. If you are trying it in iframe or FB app then try `window.top.location`

Comment: Are they within the <script>-tags?

Comment: Are you using frames? With frames you end up with a cross domain request which is blocked by some sites (like google).

Comment: You have to write ABSOLUTE path. RELATIVE path will not work as you commented `window.location = '../../member/en/member1.html';`

Answer (score 1):

If you have this javascript embedded within <script> tags it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
</script>
```

However, you cannot cause a PHP script to be included within a page you are writing with thsi javascript function: It will only redirect the browser to google or whatever other page you have set in window.location. You can include a PHP script from within a PHP page using the PHP include() or require() functions:

```
<?php
  include('file.php');
?>
```

Comment: ist a function in the header ... tags are there for all functions

Comment: window.location = "../../member/en/member.php";

Comment: As long as the page is accessible normally (for example just writing the address into the address bar and it is working there), then your `window.location = "../../member/en/member.php";` *should* work. I would check to make sure that the location is accessible normally.

Comment: full code :function callmemberpage() {

alert("callmemberpage was called");

window.location = '../../member/en/member1.html';
}

Comment: Ignore what I said about headers. That is for the PHP header() function. :P Is it still not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

Should work..

I think your javascript code contain some error so it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

So php.ini's line allow_url_fopen has nothing to do with this. It is to allow or not a url to be given to the fopen function of PHP.

Here what you want to do is to redirect a user to another page using `window.location = '/page.php'`.

Unless by open you meant getting loading inside the actual page, in this case have a look at the [mdn documentation about XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest). And you should be using jQuery's [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

That will only redirect the user to Google.

But you can't load a page in a JS variable, every browser have a "cross-domain" restriction (unless the page is on the same domain as you JS file & your visitor).

Comment: CORS issue only occur with XHR.

Comment: after the users login and his status is known i want to foreward the user to different new pages .... used google to avoid that my site is not working or not found

Comment: window.location = "../../member/en/member.php"; that is what i need or   window.location = "../../admin/en/admin.php";